# mysqli query select e.g notification query select from four other table which are constrained by a certain key value and return a singular result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi guys hope you are well. am developing an android social media application and am a bit stuck in mysqli query.

The application database comprises of feeds that can be commented, liked,reported and shared, this actions trigger a notification to be send to the concerned party and the notification data is stored in the `notification_table`. Notification information can be retrieved in the notification module in the application. My problem comes in the retrieval of notification information.

The database comprises of five tables: `feed table`, `commented table`,`likes table`,`shared table` and `notification table`. Now when a user comments on the feed the comment is saved in the commented table with a reference id to the feed table and a user id referencing to user information who commented, a notification is send to the feed owner and the notification information is saved in the notification table with the feed id reference to the feed table.

Similar chain of event occurs to the like,shared  and reported table. now how can i retrieve notification data from notification table with a `user id`

a schema of the tables is bellow

feed_table

```
| id | feed       | user_id      | time_stamp |
-----------------------------------------------
| 0  | good day   | 25470159221  | 08/08/2018 |
| 1  | bad day    | 254701594222 | 08/09/2018 |
| 2  | normal day | 254701594223 | 08/10/2018 |
```

Comment_feed_table

```
| id | feed_id|comment| user id      | time_stamp |
-----------------------------------------------
| 0  | 0      |codding| 25470159221  | 08/08/2018 |
| 1  | 1      |bad cod|254701594221  | 08/09/2018 |
| 2  | 2      |mysqli |254701594222  | 08/10/2018 |
```

user_like_table

```
| id | feed_id |user_id    | time_stamp|
---------------------------------------- 
| 0  | 1       |25470159221|08/08/2018 |  
| 1  | 1       |25470159222|08/08/2018 |  
| 2  | 0       |25470159221|09/10/2018 |
```

user_share_table

```
| id | feed_id |user_id    | time_stamp|
---------------------------------------- 
| 0  | 1       |25470159221|08/08/2018 |  
| 1  | 1       |25470159221|08/08/2018 |  
| 2  | 0       |25470159222|09/10/2018 |
```

user_notification_table

```
| id | feed_id |notificator_id    | time_stamp|
---------------------------------------- 
| 0  | 1       |25470159222       |08/08/2018 |  
| 1  | 1       |25470159229       |08/08/2018 |  
| 2  | 0       |25470159224       |09/10/2018 |
```

now can i retrieve the notification data in notification_table that involved user_id 254701594221 in DESC order of time_stamp as in who commented,liked,shared  at timely order

have tried it this way:

first retrieve feed_id of user comments, like and shared that match with notification feed_id

```
    function select_likes($con,$phone,$offset,$no_records){
    $respond=array();
    $sql="SELECT  
    user_notification.feed_id As feed_like,
    user_feed_likes.user_feed_id

    FROM user_feed_likes

    LEFT JOIN  user_notification ON user_feed_likes.user_feed_id= user_notification.feed_id
    WHERE user_feed_likes.phone = '$phone'

    GROUP BY user_notification.feed_id
    ORDER BY user_feed_likes.time_stamp desc
      LIMIT $offset,$no_records
    ";
    $results=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            //echo "\n".$value['feed_id'];
            array_push($respond,$value['feed_like']);
        }
    }
    return $respond;

}
```

repeatedly for all the tables like,share,commented
then use the ids to select from notification_table

```
function get_notification($con,$feed_id){
    $respond=array();
    $sql="SELECT  
    user_notification.id,
    user_notification.feed_id,
    user_notification.phone,
    user_notification.message,
    user_notification.tag,
    user_notification.time_stamp,
    user_credentials.username, 
    profile_pic.imagenamesized,
    user_feeds.feed,
    user_feeds.phone AS Feed_phone,
    (SELECT username FROM user_credentials WHERE phone=user_feeds.phone) AS Feed_username,
    (SELECT count(user_phone) FROM user_feed_comments WHERE feed_id=user_notification.feed_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) AS no_comments,
    (SELECT count(phone) FROM user_feed_likes WHERE user_feed_id=user_notification.feed_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) AS no_likes,
    (SELECT count(phone) FROM user_feed_shared WHERE post_id=user_notification.feed_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) AS no_shares

     FROM user_notification

    INNER JOIN user_credentials ON user_notification.phone=user_credentials.phone
    LEFT JOIN profile_pic ON user_notification.phone=profile_pic.phone
    LEFT JOIN user_feeds ON user_notification.feed_id=user_feeds.id


      WHERE user_notification.feed_id IN('".implode("','",$feed_id)."')  
      GROUP BY tag ,user_notification.feed_id desc
      ORDER BY user_notification.time_stamp desc;";
    $results=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            array_push($respond, $value);
        }
    }
    return $respond;                                                                                                                                             
}
```

The problem with this method is that it doesn't follow the orderly manner of time especially when new offset is incremented (increase in the limit page e.g Limit From 0,10 increases to Limit from 10,20).

Secondly the Group by `notification_id` does not display the last record e.g group by `notification_id` does not display the last person who commented or liked.

Lastly, I don't think the reverse psychology here applies well in database query e.g selecting first the comment,like,and share ids in different queries and then combining them and selecting the notification_table using those feed_id feels like redundant and time consuming query PLEASE HELP

Any idea to achieve notification retrieve similar to twitter or facebook will be highly appreciated thank you.

Comment: ```time_stamp``` is only DATE or DATETIME format in your db?

Comment: its DATIME format type: timestamp ,attribute: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @kevinndwasi Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of your problem. Specially, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query on how to ask SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys the solution i found was to use a sub query with union on the where clause it eases things here is the query is user

```
SELECT  
user_notification.id,
user_notification.feed_id,
user_notification.phone,
user_notification.message,
user_notification.tag,
user_notification.time_stamp,
user_credentials.username, 
profile_pic.imagenamesized,
user_feeds.feed,
user_feeds.phone AS Feed_phone,
(SELECT username FROM user_credentials WHERE phone=user_feeds.phone) AS Feed_username,
(SELECT count(user_phone) FROM user_feed_comments WHERE feed_id=user_notification.feed_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) AS no_comments,
(SELECT count(phone) FROM user_feed_likes WHERE user_feed_id=user_notification.feed_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) AS no_likes,
(SELECT count(phone) FROM user_feed_shared WHERE post_id=user_notification.feed_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) AS no_shares

 FROM user_notification

INNER JOIN user_credentials ON user_notification.phone=user_credentials.phone
LEFT JOIN profile_pic ON user_notification.phone=profile_pic.phone
LEFT JOIN user_feeds ON user_notification.feed_id=user_feeds.id


  WHERE user_notification.feed_id IN(
  SELECT feed_id FROM user_feed_comments WHERE user_phone='$phone' GROUP BY feed_id
  UNION
  SELECT user_feed_id FROM user_feed_likes WHERE phone='$phone' GROUP BY user_feed_id
  UNION
  SELECT post_id FROM user_feed_shared WHERE phone='$phone' GROUP BY post_id
  UNION
  SELECT user_feed_id FROM user_feed_reportes WHERE user_phone='$phone' GROUP BY user_feed_id )
  GROUP BY user_notification.tag,user_notification.feed_id
  ORDER BY user_notification.time_stamp desc;
```

You can see that in the where clause i used IN because there where more then one result and in the sub query i used UNION to combine the query result thanks guys. i also used the Group by in each subquery to group each tag and each notification id thanks